# Reduced formula: $\int x^m \cdot e^x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Please, I need find a reduced formula to $$\int x^m \cdot e^x dx$$ by parts integration method, I've found that every time I compute the m is reduced so: $m-1$, $m-2$, $m-3$, but I couldn't found the general formula.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I_m = \int x^m e^x dx = \int x^m d(e^x) = x^m e^x - \int m x^{m-1} e^x dx= x^m e^x - mI_{m-1} + c_{m-1}$$
\begin{align}
I_m & = x^m e^x - m \left(x^{m-1} e^x - (m-1) I_{m-2} \right) + c_{m-2}\\
& = x^m e^x - m x^{m-1} e^x + m(m-1) I_{m-2} + c_{m-2}\\
& = x^m e^x - m x^{m-1} e^x + m(m-1) x^{m-2} e^x - m(m-1)(m-2)I_{m-3} + c_{m-3}\\
& = e^x \left(x^m - m x^{m-1} + m(m-1) x^{m-2} - \cdots + (-1)^m m!\right) + c_{0}\\
& = e^x \left(\sum_{k=0}^m P(m,k)(-1)^k x^{m-k}\right) + c_0\\
& = e^x \left(\sum_{k=0}^m P(m,k)(-1)^k x^{m-k}\right) + c_0\\
& = (-1)^m \Gamma(m+1,-x) + c_0
\end{align}
where $P(m,k) = \dfrac{m!}{(m-k)!}$.

Comment: Very good, but, what do you mean with $P(m,k)$?

Comment: He appears to mean $P(m,k)=\underbrace{m(m-1)(m-2)\cdots(m-k+1)}_{k\text{ factors}}$, which is the number of permutations of size $k$ of members of a set of size $m$.